# Pull to refresh on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to make a pull to refresh on a `UIWebView` that I load a website.
The code of the `UIWebView` is pretty simple

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://the url/")

        WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }    
}
```

Does anyone have any example because no matter what I search I only found pull to refresh on tableviews and I'm not sure if it will work with this one too.

Thanks.

Update 1. After the suggestion of Sohil  the code is like this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://iremember.gr/")

        WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

            if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0){
                //reach top
                print("Reach Top")
                WebView.reload()
            }
            else {
                print("nothing")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But it doesnt even print "nothing" when I try to reload it.

Comment: Why have you added the scroll view delegate method inside the implementation of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`?

Comment: @jrturton because im a newby and when i changed it, it was ok. hahahah

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `UIScrollView` to achieve that task. Firstly, you need to check whether user is pulling the `UIWebView` 'Up' or 'Down', for that below code will help view and then reload the `UIWebView`:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

     if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0){
     //reach top
          print("Reach Top")
          webView.reload()
     }
 }
```

Make sure you have added the delegate to `UIScrollView`:

```
webView.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i added a scroll view behind the webview and i also added your code but it doesnt work.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios bro `UIWebView` has embedded `UIScrollView` so you just need to give delegate to that!

Comment: Yes you are right. I just did this and it worked. :D

Comment: make sure you include UIScrollViewDelegate and UIWebViewDelegate

Answer (score -1):

Hello You can do this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 webViewHome.scrollView.delegate = self;
    // Refresh UIControl
    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [webViewHome.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshWebview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

Refresh method 
- (void)refreshWebview {
    //TODO: refresh your data
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
   [self loadWebviewWithUrl:kLoginUrl];
}

 I add refresh control in Did Load method. then I define refresh controller method and in that, I reload my webview.
```